# Style is only applying to two elements

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I have a ToogleButton whose Content I am changing with DataTriggers this way:

```
   <Style x:Key="EstiloToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF333333" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFF8000" />
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TextBlock Text="p" FontFamily="Wingdings 3"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.5"/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TextBlock Text="q" FontFamily="Wingdings 3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0.5"/>
                                        <SkewTransform/>
                                        <RotateTransform/>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

[image]

Previously I've defined this for each button and everything worked great, but It was a lot of lines of code, so I decided to condense it in a style, and then apply the same style to all my ToggleButtons with that desired look.

So far so good, but now I have a problem: only one, or sometimes two ToggleButtons are working correctly at the same time, the rest are in blank:

[image]

Somehow the buttons are interfering to each other. Is that possible because of the style?

I have some some ugly code behind, because I need to display a Popup below the button in a special way (not easy to achieve in XAML)

```
        //Popup FFT
    private void visButtonFFT_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        popupFFT.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void visButtonFFT_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        popupFFT.IsOpen = false;
    }

    private void popupFFT_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        visButtonFFT.IsChecked = false;
    }
```

I have this code for each ToggleButton (not clever, I know, but I'm still learning)

Do you see something that can cause this strange behavior? Thanks.

EDIT: The only thing that I've changed when I moved the style from the particular ToggleButton to the resources of the UserControl is the Binding of the DataTrigger: it was targeting the actual name of the button, and I had to change it to the RelativeSource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `Style` is a `StaticResource`, I believe only one instance of the `Style` content will be created, which will then be passed around to be presented to whichever control a `Setter` is fired on.

You should be able to use the 'x:Shared' attribute to create a new instance of your style, rather than sharing the same instance across controls.

So, adding 'x:Shared=False' to your first line:

```
<Style x:Key="EstiloToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" x:Shared ="False" >
<!-- Your code -->
```

Should do the trick.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx): **x:Shared Attribute**

> When set to false, modifies WPF resource-retrieval behavior so that
>   requests for the attributed resource create a new instance for each
>   request instead of sharing the same instance for all requests.

Edit: Forgot to mention, this relies on your `Style` residing in a `ResourceDictionary` (it should based on where you say you've placed your style).

Comment: Wow, I wasted like 2 hours restyling all over again and again. Thank you. Why I never heard of this... This is the whole point of using styles, right? Reusing the same behavior

Comment: Weirdly, I'd never actually had to use it before. My explanation might not be the most in depth, I made a little mock up and had a look at what was happening using Snoop, and it seemed the `TextBlock` in the `ContentPresenter` was jumping from button to button, which reminded my about the `Shared Attribute`. Glad it helped =D